# Add rows based on column date with two column unique key - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have a dataframe like:

```
Number Country StartDate EndDate
12     US      1/1/2023  12/1/2023
12     Mexico  1/1/2024  12/1/2024
```

And what I am trying to do is:

```
Number Country Date
12     US      1/1/2023  
12     US      2/1/2023
12     US      3/1/2023
12     US      4/1/2023
12     US      5/1/2023
12     US      6/1/2023
12     US      7/1/2023
12     US      8/1/2023
12     US      9/1/2023
12     US      10/1/2023
12     US      11/1/2023
12     US      12/1/2023
12     Mexico      1/1/2024  
12     Mexico      2/1/2024
12     Mexico      3/1/2024
12     Mexico      4/1/2024
12     Mexico      5/1/2024
12     Mexico      6/1/2024
12     Mexico      7/1/2024
12     Mexico      8/1/2024
12     Mexico      9/1/2024
12     Mexico      10/1/2024
12     Mexico      11/1/2024
12     Mexico      12/1/2024
```

This problem is very similar to [Adding rows for each month in a dataframe based on column date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55844141/adding-rows-for-each-month-in-a-dataframe-based-on-column-date)

However that problem only accounts for the unique key being one column. In this example the unique key is the Number and the Country.

This is what I am currently doing however, it only accounts for one column 'Number' and I need to include both Number and Country as they are the unique key.

```
df1 = pd.concat([pd.Series(r.Number, pd.date_range(start = r.StartDate, end = r.EndDate, freq='MS')) 
                    for r in df1.itertuples()]).reset_index().drop_duplicates()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create the range then `explode`

```
df['New']= [pd.date_range(start = x, end = y, freq='MS') for x , y in zip(df.pop('StartDate'),df.pop('EndDate'))]
df=df.explode('New')
Out[54]: 
   Number Country        New
0      12      US 2023-01-01
0      12      US 2023-02-01
0      12      US 2023-03-01
0      12      US 2023-04-01
0      12      US 2023-05-01
0      12      US 2023-06-01
0      12      US 2023-07-01
0      12      US 2023-08-01
0      12      US 2023-09-01
0      12      US 2023-10-01
0      12      US 2023-11-01
0      12      US 2023-12-01
1      12  Mexico 2024-01-01
1      12  Mexico 2024-02-01
1      12  Mexico 2024-03-01
1      12  Mexico 2024-04-01
1      12  Mexico 2024-05-01
1      12  Mexico 2024-06-01
1      12  Mexico 2024-07-01
1      12  Mexico 2024-08-01
1      12  Mexico 2024-09-01
1      12  Mexico 2024-10-01
1      12  Mexico 2024-11-01
1      12  Mexico 2024-12-01
```